# Rhomobile send logfile

Tags: android, logging, rhomobile, rhodes

I am new to rhomobile so let me begin.

I am able to view the device rho-log file on my android device. There is a few options when the window opens "Refresh,Clear,Send,Close".

Question 1. When I press send where does it get sent to?

Question 2. Is it possible to send it somewhere so I could download it as  .txt file on a desktop and view it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In the **rhoconfig.txt** file of the root directory, there is a **logserver** property that points to a URL where the log will be posted to, **logserver = 'http://yourloggerapp.heroku.com'**

You can find the logging application to stand up on Heroku (quickly, but can be deployed anywhere) [here](https://github.com/rhomobile/rhologs).  This application is set up to hook into an Amazon S3 server, but again, can be modified to store the log files anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can set this variable at runtime:

```
  Rho::RhoConfig.logserver = 'http://yourserver.com/logs'
```

Or this fixed parameter in rhoconfig.txt:

```
  logserver = 'http://yourserver.com/logs
```

When the user press the "Send" button your server will receive a POST request in this URL:

```
  http://yourserver.com/logs/client_log
```